# How can i modify padding,margins and other css properties when using bulma framework?

Tags: css, sass, bulma

My project consist of  a custom.scss file, In this file  i am importing all of the bulma modules, in the same file i am also importing my custom modules. The sass preprocessor compiles it to a custom.css file. I am having problems in modifying the bulma defined classes. For example i want to modify navbar-item but it always defaults to the bulma values.
This is my custom.scss file.

```
@charset "utf-8";
// My Custom Imports

@import "utilities/_all";
@import "layout/_generic";
@import "layout/_navigation";


// Bulma Imports
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/container.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/title.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/section.sass";
```

This is my _navigation file

```
.navbar  {
   .navbar-end {
          .navbar-item {
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
}
}
```

Comment: hi @Awais
To overwrite the css of any frameword you have to increase the specificity (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity ).

other methods are using !important after style and importing you custom file after all the files of framework

Comment: I think your custom styles should be at the bottom so the cascade can overwrite bulma's styles.

Comment: I brought my custom imports down below the bulma imports but now even the custom imports that were working are broken may be   I will add a second custom.css file below the main css file